# Summing one ArrayList of Integers to another ArrayList of Integers, gives error: variable expected

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have two ArrayList of 6 elements in my Android application. Let's call them ArrayList "A" and "B". Each object in my class has this line in the constructor:

```
likes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

I could also add this line in the constructor (I'm not sure which one is better, but I want to initialize the size to 6, and all elements should be 0):

```
likes = new ArrayList<>(Collections.nCopies(6, 0));
```

I have a method in my class called Calculate, which is supposed to take a new ArrayList of Integers, B, of the same size as A, as a parameter. Then add / sum B with this object's ArrayList, A.

Here is the method:

```
public void Calculate(ArrayList<Integer> likes){
    for(int i = 0; i < likes.size(); i++){
        this.likes.get(i) += likes.get(i);
        //this.likes.get(i) = 3;
    }
}
```

I'm getting a red line under the line *this.likes.get(i)*, saying:

> Variable Expected

Even if I try to just say *this.likes.get(i) = 3;* I get the same error.

Let's say A = {0,0,0,0,0,0}, and B = {1,0,0,-1,1,0}

What is the correct way to sum to ArrayList, to make A = {1,0,0,-1,1,0}?

Comment: this is a getter, hence a method, you cannot assign a value to a method !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't assign a value to a value such as `this.likes.get(i)`.
You can only assign values to variables.

To modify the `i`'th element of an `ArrayList` you should use the `ArrayList`'s `set` method:

```
this.likes.set(i,this.likes.get(i) + likes.get(i));
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to use [set(index,value)](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html#set(int,%20E)) because there is no container on the left side to hold the value so hence the error , so you can pass the resultant value to list to set it at the desired position

```
this.likes.set(i,this.likes.get(i) += likes.get(i));
```

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to assign value to a method, try something like :

```
    int oldLikesCount = this.likes.get(i);     
    this.likes.set(i,oldLikesCount +likes.get(i));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use incorrectly the get method (used only to retrieve data), instead you must use the set method to assign a value in the ArrayList

[image]

```
public void Calculate(ArrayList<Integer> likes){
    for(int i = 0; i < likes.size(); i++){
        this.likes.set(i, (this.likes.get(i) + likes.get(i));
        //this.likes.set(i, 3);
    }
}
```