# Java "Variable Expected" error on list.get(0) = 2

Tags: java, list, arraylist

Here is a simple java code that I wrote:

```
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(0);
    list.get(0) = 2; // Trying to set first list element's value to 2
```

The third line gives me an error, it says:

```
java: unexpected type
required: variable
found:    value
```

Does anyone know why I am getting this type of error?

Comment: do you mean `==`?

Comment: Just read a javadoc https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#add(int,E)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Variable expected java vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47741603/variable-expected-java-vector) and [Summing one ArrayList of Integers to another ArrayList of Integers, gives error: variable expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47284958/summing-one-arraylist-of-integers-to-another-arraylist-of-integers-gives-error)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Variable expected java vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47741603/variable-expected-java-vector)

Answer (score 2):

set() method is used to set the element in the particular index

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(0);
list.set(0, 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this to add in beginning

```
list.add(0, 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

`get(int index)` is a getter and it will return `Integer` from your list but it doesn't allow you to set it's value.
To set value at given index, use `set(int index, Integer element)`.

Keep in mind that using `set(int index, Integer element)` is for updating your list - so in your case `list.get(0)` cannot return `null`. If this object doesn't exist, use `add(Integer element)` as you did before :)

Answer (score 1):

If "Trying to set first list element's value to 2" is what you are trying to do:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(2); // add '2' at the first available position, ie 0th index
System.out.println(list.get(0)); // get the value from 0th index
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java method calls (like `list.get(_)`) cannot be lvalues (left-hands of the `=` operator). Therefore, it is illegal to assign values to method calls, even if they are getters. Indeed, a getter may return and compute anything, even be a constant function always returning `42`. What variable should receive the right-hand value then?

As other answers suggest, please consider using `list.set(_, _)` method.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in expression

```
list.get(0) = 2;
```

Methd List#get(int index) returns the element at the specified position in the List. So left side of expression is a value not a variable. You can't set value to another value.

Use List#add method to append element to the end of List:

```
  list.add(2);
```

or to add element to specified position 0:

```
  list.add(0,2);
```

If you need to replace element at particular index use List#set method:

```
  list.set(0,2);
```